# Getting: Possible index corruption detected. Run DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: sql-server, linux, errors, sql-server-2017

When I connect to the database and run a command on some catalogs, I get **Msg 9100, Level 23**

```
1> SELECT * FROM sys.databases;
2> GO
Msg 9100, Level 23, State 2, Server x230, Line 1
Possible index corruption detected. Run DBCC CHECKDB.
```

In the logs, I get

```
spid51      Error: 9100, Severity: 23, State: 2.
spid51      Possible index corruption detected. Run DBCC CHECKDB.
```

However, when I run `DBCC CHECKDB`, this shows up in the logs,

```
spid51      DBCC CHECKDB (mssqlsystemresource) executed by sa found 0 errors and repaired 0 errors. Elapsed time: 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds.
```

I was connected with *Single User Mode* over DAC.

### Full `DBCC CHECKDB`

In the logs this shows up,

```
DBCC results for 'mssqlsystemresource'.
Service Broker Msg 9675, State 1: Message Types analyzed: 14.
Service Broker Msg 9676, State 1: Service Contracts analyzed: 6.
Service Broker Msg 9667, State 1: Services analyzed: 3.
Service Broker Msg 9668, State 1: Service Queues analyzed: 3.
Service Broker Msg 9669, State 1: Conversation Endpoints analyzed: 0.
Service Broker Msg 9674, State 1: Conversation Groups analyzed: 0.
Service Broker Msg 9670, State 1: Remote Service Bindings analyzed: 0.
Service Broker Msg 9605, State 1: Conversation Priorities analyzed: 0.
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrscols'.
There are 1700 rows in 20 pages for object "sys.sysrscols".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrowsets'.
There are 223 rows in 3 pages for object "sys.sysrowsets".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysclones'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysclones".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysallocunits'.
There are 271 rows in 3 pages for object "sys.sysallocunits".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysfiles1'.
There are 2 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysfiles1".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysseobjvalues'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysseobjvalues".
DBCC results for 'sys.syspriorities'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syspriorities".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysdbfrag'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysdbfrag".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysfgfrag'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysfgfrag".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysdbfiles'.
There are 2 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysdbfiles".
DBCC results for 'sys.syspru'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syspru".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysbrickfiles'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysbrickfiles".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysphfg'.
There are 1 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysphfg".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysprufiles'.
There are 2 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysprufiles".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysftinds'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysftinds".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysowners'.
There are 14 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysowners".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysdbreg'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysdbreg".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysprivs'.
There are 123 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysprivs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysschobjs'.
There are 3665 rows in 71 pages for object "sys.sysschobjs".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscsrowgroups'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syscsrowgroups".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysextsources'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysextsources".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysexttables'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysexttables".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysextfileformats'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysextfileformats".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysmultiobjvalues'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysmultiobjvalues".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscolpars'.
There are 24408 rows in 464 pages for object "sys.syscolpars".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxlgns'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysxlgns".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxsrvs'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysxsrvs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysnsobjs'.
There are 3 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysnsobjs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysusermsgs'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysusermsgs".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscerts'.
There are 5 rows in 3 pages for object "sys.syscerts".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrmtlgns'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysrmtlgns".
DBCC results for 'sys.syslnklgns'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syslnklgns".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxprops'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysxprops".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysscalartypes'.
There are 34 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysscalartypes".
DBCC results for 'sys.systypedsubobjs'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.systypedsubobjs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysidxstats'.
There are 1033 rows in 18 pages for object "sys.sysidxstats".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysiscols'.
There are 1160 rows in 8 pages for object "sys.sysiscols".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysendpts'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysendpts".
DBCC results for 'sys.syswebmethods'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syswebmethods".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysbinobjs'.
There are 23 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysbinobjs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysaudacts'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysaudacts".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysobjvalues'.
There are 4547 rows in 1267 pages for object "sys.sysobjvalues".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscscolsegments'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syscscolsegments".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscsdictionaries'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syscsdictionaries".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysclsobjs'.
There are 21 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysclsobjs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrowsetrefs'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysrowsetrefs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysremsvcbinds'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysremsvcbinds".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxmitqueue'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysxmitqueue".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysrts'.
There are 1 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysrts".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysconvgroup'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysconvgroup".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysdesend'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysdesend".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysdercv'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysdercv".
DBCC results for 'sys.syssingleobjrefs'.
There are 6686 rows in 28 pages for object "sys.syssingleobjrefs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysmultiobjrefs'.
There are 1117 rows in 6 pages for object "sys.sysmultiobjrefs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysguidrefs'.
There are 4 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysguidrefs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysfoqueues'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysfoqueues".
DBCC results for 'sys.syschildinsts'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syschildinsts".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscompfragments'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syscompfragments".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysftsemanticsdb'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysftsemanticsdb".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysftstops'.
There are 15829 rows in 121 pages for object "sys.sysftstops".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysftproperties'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysftproperties".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxmitbody'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysxmitbody".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysfos'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysfos".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysqnames'.
There are 1111 rows in 15 pages for object "sys.sysqnames".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxmlcomponent'.
There are 6478 rows in 32 pages for object "sys.sysxmlcomponent".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxmlfacet'.
There are 392 rows in 3 pages for object "sys.sysxmlfacet".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysxmlplacement'.
There are 11304 rows in 85 pages for object "sys.sysxmlplacement".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysobjkeycrypts'.
There are 848 rows in 43 pages for object "sys.sysobjkeycrypts".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysasymkeys'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sysasymkeys".
DBCC results for 'sys.syssqlguides'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syssqlguides".
DBCC results for 'sys.sysbinsubobjs'.
There are 3 rows in 1 pages for object "sys.sysbinsubobjs".
DBCC results for 'sys.syssoftobjrefs'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syssoftobjrefs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sqlagent_jobs'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sqlagent_jobs".
DBCC results for 'sys.sqlagent_jobsteps'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sqlagent_jobsteps".
DBCC results for 'sys.sqlagent_job_history'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sqlagent_job_history".
DBCC results for 'sys.sqlagent_jobsteps_logs'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.sqlagent_jobsteps_logs".
DBCC results for 'sys.plan_persist_query_text'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.plan_persist_query_text".
DBCC results for 'sys.plan_persist_query'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.plan_persist_query".
DBCC results for 'sys.plan_persist_plan'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.plan_persist_plan".
DBCC results for 'sys.plan_persist_runtime_stats'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.plan_persist_runtime_stats".
DBCC results for 'sys.plan_persist_runtime_stats_interval'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.plan_persist_runtime_stats_interval".
DBCC results for 'sys.plan_persist_context_settings'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.plan_persist_context_settings".
DBCC results for 'sys.plan_persist_query_hints'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.plan_persist_query_hints".
DBCC results for 'sys.plan_persist_query_template_parameterization'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.plan_persist_query_template_parameterization".
DBCC results for 'sys.plan_persist_wait_stats'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.plan_persist_wait_stats".
DBCC results for 'sys.queue_messages_1977058079'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.queue_messages_1977058079".
DBCC results for 'sys.queue_messages_2009058193'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.queue_messages_2009058193".
DBCC results for 'sys.queue_messages_2041058307'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.queue_messages_2041058307".
DBCC results for 'sys.filestream_tombstone_2073058421'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.filestream_tombstone_2073058421".
DBCC results for 'sys.syscommittab'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.syscommittab".
DBCC results for 'sys.filetable_updates_2105058535'.
There are 0 rows in 0 pages for object "sys.filetable_updates_2105058535".
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

## On Master

In `sqlcmd`

Here is the full result of the `DBCC CHECKDB` command when connected to the master database.

```
1> DBCC CHECKDB;
2> GO
Msg 8939, Level 16, State 106, Server x230, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 60, index ID 1, partition ID 281474980642816, alloc unit ID 281474980642816 (type In-row data), page (1:91). Test (hdr->m_freeCnt == freeCnt) failed. Values are 7820 and 7864.
Msg 8928, Level 16, State 1, Server x230, Line 1
Object ID 60, index ID 1, partition ID 281474980642816, alloc unit ID 281474980642816 (type In-row data): Page (1:91) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Msg 8976, Level 16, State 1, Server x230, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 60, index ID 1, partition ID 281474980642816, alloc unit ID 281474980642816 (type In-row data). Page (1:91) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:275) and previous (1:92) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Msg 8978, Level 16, State 1, Server x230, Line 1
Table error: Object ID 60, index ID 1, partition ID 281474980642816, alloc unit ID 281474980642816 (type In-row data). Page (1:410) is missing a reference from previous page (1:91). Possible chain linkage problem.
DBCC results for 'master'.
```

### STDOUT from `sqlservr`

When I run `DBCC CHECKDB` on master I get,

```
2018-01-04 19:29:06.13 spid51      Possible index corruption detected. Run DBCC CHECKDB.
2018-01-04 19:29:25.12 spid51      DBCC CHECKDB (master) executed by sa found 4 errors and repaired 0 errors. Elapsed time: 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds.  
2018-01-04 19:29:25.12 spid51      Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
2018-01-04 19:29:25.12 spid51      **Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x000000080D89BC10
2018-01-04 19:29:25.12 spid51      ***Stack Dump being sent to /var/opt/mssql/log/SQLDump0001.txt
2018-01-04 19:29:25.12 spid51      * *******************************************************************************
2018-01-04 19:29:25.13 spid51      *
2018-01-04 19:29:25.13 spid51      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2018-01-04 19:29:25.13 spid51      *   01/04/18 19:29:25 spid 51
2018-01-04 19:29:25.13 spid51      *
2018-01-04 19:29:25.13 spid51      * DBCC database corruption
2018-01-04 19:29:25.13 spid51      *
2018-01-04 19:29:25.13 spid51      * Input Buffer 50 bytes -
2018-01-04 19:29:25.13 spid51      *             DBCC CHECKDB; 
2018-01-04 19:29:25.13 spid51      *  
2018-01-04 19:29:25.13 spid51      * *******************************************************************************
2018-01-04 19:29:25.13 spid51      * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-04 19:29:25.14 spid51      * Short Stack Dump
2018-01-04 19:29:25.19 spid51      Stack Signature for the dump is 0x000000000000014C
2018-01-04 19:29:30.29 spid51      External dump process return code 0x20000001.
External dump process returned no errors.
2018-01-04 19:29:30.62 spid51      DBCC CHECKDB (mssqlsystemresource) executed by sa found 0 errors and repaired 0 errors. Elapsed time: 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds.  
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      **Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x000000080D89BC10
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      ***Stack Dump being sent to /var/opt/mssql/log/SQLDump0002.txt
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      * *******************************************************************************
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      *
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      *   01/04/18 19:29:30 spid 51
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      *
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      * DBCC database corruption
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      *
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      * Input Buffer 50 bytes -
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      *             DBCC CHECKDB; 
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      *  
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      * *******************************************************************************
2018-01-04 19:29:30.63 spid51      * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2018-01-04 19:29:30.64 spid51      * Short Stack Dump
2018-01-04 19:29:30.69 spid51      Stack Signature for the dump is 0x000000000000014C
2018-01-04 19:29:37.80 spid51      External dump process return code 0x20000001.
External dump process returned no errors.
```

Comment: Discussion for this question has been **[moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71215/discussion-on-question-by-evan-carroll-getting-possible-index-corruption-detect)**.